# Sql query to find difference between date

Tags: sql

I need a sql query which will find the difference between two dates . I have already tried the   between clause query but It include the Starting date . But  I need a query that exclude the start date . and so please provide me a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) method

E.g:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SELECT DATE_ADD(start_date,INTERVAL 1 DAY),end_date);
```

If you want to exclude the start_date, or change the interval as per your requirements